# Where are all these triangles coming from?

Tags: modeling

I made a soda can in blender when i select the can it says it has 2k triangles and when i select the tab it says it has 1k triangles, so why is the total 60k? Im importing it to roblox studio so it wont work if it has over 10k triangles
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It comes from the subdivision modifier.

Comment: In _Edit Mode_, the real geometry is shown. In _Object Mode_, it shows the geometry generated by the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier. //Edit: @AlexandreMarcati Oops, you were a bit quicker. I shouldn't explain so much...

Comment: How do I decrease the ammount of triangles down to under 10k= ive already decimated it but its still 22k?

Comment: just remove the subdivision modifiers. Or reduce the subdivision levels to 1 instead of 2.

Comment: @eiavops Either delete the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier or reduce the levels, or make the base mesh much simpler or use a _Remesh_ modifier. But all of this will change the look of your model, because really smooth and rounded shapes or fine details need more geometry.